# invalid syntax running python manage.py migrate

Tags: python, django

After I enter:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

I get an error on this line:

```
archive_files = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket=settings.ARCHIVE_BUCKET, Prefix=f"{org.id}/")["Contents"]
                                                                                     ^
```

[image: trace]

I don't understand why django 2.0.3 is complaining.

Comment: Python supports string interpolation in 3.6 and onwards https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/string-interpolation So by running this with `python3.5` the compiler does not understand what you are saying there.

Comment: We need to see the code being mentioned, and the error; and both need to be here as text.

Comment: Please copy the code (traceback), do *not* post an *image* of the traceback. You can copy from Ubuntu terminals with Ctrl+Shift+C.

Comment: Here is the traceback  https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkHZL.png

Comment: @NathanKirui: please do **not** post **images** of errors, code, tracebacks, etc.

Comment: I typed the last line from the image in the question for you. It would be nice if you would do this next time ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the traceback we see that the caret points to a [*string interpolation* [PEP-0498]](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/). This feature is supported since [python-3.6](/questions/tagged/python-3.6), but you run your code with:

```
python3.5 manage.py runserver
```

so the interpreter does not understand this string interpolation.

You basically have two options:

1. try to run this with [python-3.6](/questions/tagged/python-3.6) (or higher), although there is of course always a risk that something is broken then:

   ```
   python3.6 manage.py runserver
   ```
2. perform proper formatting, replace:

   ```
   prefix=f"{org.id}/"
   ```

   with:

   ```
   prefix="{}/".format(org.id)
   ```

or some other way to format this.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using format strings with python 3.5, however support for formatted string literals was not added until python 3.6. More information can be found in the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings). You will either need to update your python version or format the string another way. e.g. `"{}/".format(org.id)`